# I have a question about data controls

Tags: asp.net, controls, data-controls

I used a few data controls, but I am not experienced enough to know with what controls to stick and with which not to stick..

If gridview has so many events and properties why would I choose to use: ListView, Repeater, FormsView?

When will I choose to use Repeater or FormsView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had typed up some long, verbose answer, but found [this article](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/475/comparing-listview-with-gridviewdatalist-and-repeater/)  that illustrates each data control's supported functionalities.

The most flexible data control is the ListView, where you have full control over the layout, paging, sorting, grouping.

The repeater doesn't have any bells and whistles except for a flexible layout.  Quick and dirty data displaying.